# Pythons's AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'errors'

Tags: python

I know it's been here a lot of times but I didn't find the right answer for my case.
**First:** I'm making an easy database system (for myself) that will run with no hashes etc. (for now at least). Now I got stuck.

```
import sys
import os

filename = ""
database = ""
path = ""
table = ""

class Nollty:
    returns = 0
    errors = 0

    def __init__(self, filename, database):
        self.filename = filename
        self.database = database
        self.path = self.filename + "databases/" + self.database
        openfile = open(self.path + "/db_required", "r")
        if not openfile.errors:
            self.returns = 1
        if not os.path.exists(self.path + "/db_required"):
            self.returns = 0
        openfile.close();

    def select(self, table):
        errors = 0
        self.table = table
        openfile = open(self.path + "/" + self.table, "r")
        if not openfile.errors:
            errors = 1
        if not os.path.exists(self.path + "/" + self.table):
            errors = 0
        openfile.close();


nollty = Nollty("", "test")
if nollty.returns == 1:
    print "Successfully connected to the database!"

query = nollty.select("aaa_auto")
if query.errors == 0:
    print "Successfully chosen the table!"
```

The error output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/spotrudloff/Python/Nollty/nollty.py", line 40, in <module>
if query.errors == 0:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'errors'
```

The problem is probably that I'm PHP programmer, and I learnt Python today in a few hours (so my thinking is still "PHPy").

Thanks for all the responses.

Comment: make the select function return something...

Comment: Note that `openfile.errors` almost certainly isn't what you think it is. It isn't set to an error code - it's just a string specifying the error handler to be used for encoding. In your example code, it will always have the value `None`. (See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.errors)).

Comment: +1-ing your -1, as I found this helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select()` doesn't return an explicit value, so it has a `NoneType` return value.  Change your code so that `select()` will return either 1 or 0, depending on the success or failure of your code.

Answer (score 4):

Your use of `returns` and `errors` as class variables doesn't seem like a good idea. There is only *one* instance of each of those variables, no matter how many instances of `Nollty` you create. Instead, do this:

```
def __init__(self, filename, database):
    self.returns = 0
    self.errors = 0
    # rest of __init__
```

Next, the use of `returns` to indicate a return value doesn't seem like a good idea either. In Python, one would normally raise an *exception* to indicate a problem in the constructor. That way, the caller can't simply ignore a problem by forgetting to check `returns`.

Similarly, use an exception from `select()` to indicate a problem with the parameter. My recommendation would be to *eliminate* both `returns` and `errors`.

You're also not returning any value at all from `select`, so that's why `query` ends up being `None` (in Python, `None` is a special value). You either want to return something useful from `select()`, or don't assign its result to anything if it doesn't return a useful value.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like select() is not returning a value, so it defaults to a NoneType (null). Alternatively (what you probably meant to do), change query to nollty.

Comment: The name is `None`, not `null`. `null` is a literal "absence of a [n object] value" in languages like Java, C#, C++ and [`nil` in] Objective-C. In Python, `None` is the sole inhabitant object of the `NoneType` type. To see that `None` isn't the same as `null` (it is still an object), consider: `dir(None)`.

Comment: I understand that. I was merely using it as a quick way to describe what NoneType was in terms of something available in other languages (such as php, which uses null).

Answer (score 0):

The errors variable in your select method is a local variable.  You need to explicity set the class errors variable.  Also, as others suggested your select method has no return statement.  From your code it looks like you are trying to access the errors variable of nollty, but you are checking for it in query variable which is logically a None.

You have two options depending on what your objective is.  Return the errors from select or set self.errors = errors before your select method returns.  Or do both if you like, as below.  Usually you'd probably return False if the select failed and True if it succeeded, but it's not required.

```
class Nollty:
    ...
    def select(self,table):
        ...
        self.errors = errors
        return errors

errs = nollty.select("aaa_auto")
if nollty.errors == 0:
    print "Successfully chosen the table!"

##functionally equivalent
#if errs==0:
#    print "Successfully chosen the table!"
```

Comment: Ok, I have resolved the problem with just using the return. I have also rewritten __returns__ with exceptions. Thank you all. :)